# Alternative SSH Application to Plink

Tags: ssh, cvs, tortoisecvs, plink

I have recently started having problems with TortoiseCVS, or more specifically with plink, the SSH application that comes with it. The IP address it tries to connect to can not be changed and is stuck with the old CVS repository's IP. Downloading plink from it's home site and calling from the command line still has this problem.

TortoiseCVS has the option to choose the SSH application it uses and I was wondering which other alternatives there are that I can use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth, [plink](http://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/x86/plink.exe) is just a command-line version of putty written by the same guy.

I think [jsight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687/alternative-ssh-application-to-plink#22700) probably has the right idea.

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure this is a problem with plink?  It sounds to me like you have CVS/Root files lying around that still point to the old cvs ip address.  In general, CVS doesn't make changing repositories into a fun process.  Since you are using Windows, if you install WinCVS with macros support (Python module loaded) it has a macro that can be used to mass change CVS roots.

Otherwise, its up to you to script the process.

FWIW, I've used plink quite a bit and never had a similar problem.

Comment: Actually this is trivial *if* you are clever _beforehand_. Just like you can create `Host` lines in your `.ssh/config` file with OpenSSH, you can do similar things with PuTTY by creating configurations going by a certain name. Then you could create configurations by names that are entirely independent of the hostname/IP and refer the `CVSROOT` to those names. This way you can later tell your SSH client (be it Plink or OpenSSH's `ssh`) to point to a different underlying hostname or IP, whereas your working copies need no update. At most you need to update the saved host keys (`HostKeyAlias`).

Answer (score 2):

Putty is probably the best SSH client out there:

http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you stick with PuTTY too. You might find it useful to run Pageant in conjunction with Plink to avoid having to type in the passphrase.

But if you want to research alternatives you should review this Wikipedia resource:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_SSH_clients

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to jsight (and Mark Biek for pointing out the connection between plink and putty) I decided to investigate more fully.

It turned out that plink had been using the "Default Settings" stored Session that I set up for putty and wasn't allowing them to be overridden.

edit:

> The Geek: Also, this is a good example why you should always, always use DNS/hostnames instead of the IP address directly.

The problem was nothing to do with the IP address change, and in this case the DNS changed as well. I can see your point, but this isn't the 'good example' you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth trying Tunnelier from [www.bitvise.com](http://www.bitvise.com)

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN, at least, has an option called Relocate which you can use if the location of the repository has changed.

Also, this is a good example why you should always, always use DNS/hostnames instead of the IP address directly.

Comment: Yeah, except the way working copies are stored on disk make it trivial to update the working copy to point elsewhere. (It's `svn switch --relocate`, btw.) For CVS this would be more cumbersome until you're smart about it upfront.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using TortoiseCVS 1.10.9 on Vista Business, and ext connections to my server were regularly crashing TortoisePlink.

I downloaded the latest puTTY (0.60) and set TortoiseCVS to point to the plink included with this puTTY (CVS->Preferences->Tools). The command line options appear to be the same, but one difference is that TortoisePlink pops up a password dialog if you don't have a keypair for your server. Regular plink does not. So you have to either create the keypair (puttygen, I believe) or specify a -pw on the command line options (very BAD security idea).

Answer (score -1):

+1 for PuTTy... been using it for the last decade and never needed anything else!